# How can I initialize multiple states with api with React hooks?

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I've states like `versions`, `platformlist`, `buildslist`, `latestversion`, `latestplatform`, and `latestbuild`.

Versions are received from an API call and platform list and build a list from another API call which uses results from the 1st API.
But as soon as I set to state 'versions' I can't access it for the second API as a parameter since setState in hooks is asynchronous. I am doing it inside useEffect with dependency array as `[]` ("I can't have anything inside this array as a requirement.").
So I need the setStates to follow a specific order in a synchronous nature.
I need the component to be rendered with all the states initialized. In short one state needs to be set after the another one has been successfully set since it needs its value in the API.

What could be my best approach?

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example of your component and hooks. State updates are asynchronous in nature, but within the enclosure of the effect hook callback you should still have a current `versions` reference to use for further API calls. Update your question and we can better see what you're working with.